# Two NSMutableArrays in one UITableView with custom cells in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

In my iOS app, I am having two **NSMutableArray**

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    NSMutableArray *arrOne;
    NSMutableArray *arrTwo;
}
```

declared in my implementation file and one **UITableView**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

declared inside *MyController.h*

What I want is to load both those array contents in the same table where *arrOne* content at first and *arrTwo* contants next.

Below is the way how I got number of table rows

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    if ([arrOne count] > 0 && [arrTwo count] > 0) {
        return [arrOne count] + [arrTwo count];
    } else if ([arrTwo count] > 0) {
        return [arrTwo count];
    } else {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

and below is the place where I tried to create my table cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"myTable";

    if ([arrOne count] > 0 && [arrOne count] > indexPath.row) {

        UITableViewCell *defaultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (defaultCell == nil) {
            defaultCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }       
        return defaultCell;

    } else {

        MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

With the above code, and assume *arrOne* has only one element, the *tableView* supposed to display first cell white and all others with my custom cell. Instead, it display, first cell white as expected and again some cells in the middle (5, 9, 13...) also in white. Cannot identify the reason yet. Any idea why?

If this is not the correct way of implementing two arrays in a single table view, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `arrOne` contains only a single element (as you say it does) and `arrTwo` is empty, then you will have 10 total cells according to `numberOfRowsInSection`. The first cell will be a `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` cell, and the next 9 should be `MyTableViewCell` cells.

The reason you're seeing multiple `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` cells is because you're using the same cell identifier. Move your ID declaration inside each of the `if`/`else` statements and use a different identifier for each cell type.

```
if ([arrOne count] > 0 && [arrOne count] > indexPath.row) {
    static NSString *defaultTableIdentifier = @"defaultReuse";
    UITableViewCell *defaultCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:defaultTableIdentifier];

    if (defaultCell == nil) {
        defaultCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:defaultTableIdentifier];
    }       
    return defaultCell;

} else {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"myCustomCellReuse";
    MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

(Also, is your Nib name different than the class name? `MyTableViewCell` vs `MyTableCell`. Because you declare a cell of the class `MyTableViewCell` and then load a nib named `MyTableCell`.)

Comment: In general, if you're using multiple types of cells and you see the wrong kind showing up at strange intervals, odds are it's a problem with how you're reusing cells.